# Enum type as decorator parameter

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript2.0

Is it possible to pass enum type as parameter to a decorator function?

```
export class A {
    @AsEnum(SomeEnum)
    name: string;
}

export enum SomeEnum { A, B, C}

export function AsEnum(type): any {
    return (target, propert) => {
      return {
            get: function(): Object {
                return type; // type is undefined
            },
        }
    };
}
```

Here type is always undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order of your code.
If you'll do:

```
console.log("the enum: ", SomeEnum);
export enum SomeEnum { A, B, C}
```

You'll get:

> the enum: undefined

You need to place the declaration of `SomeEnum` before using it when calling the decorator:

```
function AsEnum(type): any {
    return (target, propert) => {
      return {
            get: function(): Object {
                return type; // type is undefined
            },
        }
    };
}

enum SomeEnum { A, B, C}

class A {
    @AsEnum(SomeEnum)
    name: string;
}
```

The interpreter hasn't evaluated the enum yet when you try to use it for the decorator.